# How can i create Turtle clones and append them into a list?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to write a Program, that draws 5 squares in 3 rows. Every second square is a different color.

So I have prepared the squares so far

```
sq1 = turtle.Turtle()
sq1.shape("square")
sq1.hideturtle()
sq1.color("red")
sq1.begin_fill()

sq2 = turtle.Turtle()
sq2.shape("square")
sq2.hideturtle()
sq2.color("black")
sq2.begin_fill()
```

As you can imagine, typing in 15 clone.turtles and a different location for each of them will take forever. My goal is to create a simple list for this purpose. Just I don't know how to put all of the different squares into the list and how to manage to move them to different locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the turtles in a `for` loop, and append the turtle to a list in each iteration.

You can define a function:

```
import turtle

def draw_squares(rows, cols, x=0, y=0, size=20):
    colors = ['red', 'black']
    square = []
    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(rows):
            t = turtle.Turtle('square')
            t.penup()
            t.shapesize(size / 20)
            t.goto(i * size + x, j * size + y)
            t.color(colors[(i + j) % 2])
            square.append(t)
    return squares

squares = draw_squares(3, 5, size=40)
```

Output:

[image]

Where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the center of the bottom-left square, `size` is the size of each square in pixels, and `rows` and `cols` are the number of rows and columns in the checkerboard.

**UPDATE**

As requested in the comments, here is how we can change the width, height and spacing between each rectangle:

```
import turtle

def draw_squares(rows, cols, x=-170, y=0, w=80, h=40, space=5):
    colors = ['red', 'black']
    square = []
    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(rows):
            t = turtle.Turtle('square')
            t.penup()
            t.shapesize(h / 20, w / 20)
            t.goto(i * space + i * w + x,j * space + j * h + y)
            t.color('white', colors[(i + j) % 2])
            square.append(t)
    return squares

squares = draw_squares(3, 5)
```

Output:

[image]

Where `w` is the width, `h` is the height and `space` is the spacing.

Comment: Hello Ann Zen,
thank you for your response!
Is it possible, to somehow include space inbetween the squares? As shown in the image:
![Click for the image](https://s20.directupload.net/images/201130/bof47rc8.png).

Also, is it possible to change the squares width and height?

Comment: @Bob Updated --

Comment: Thank you Ann Zen, this is awesome!

Comment: This crashes after drawing with `NameError: name 'squares' is not defined` as you use two different names for your list of square in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned *cloning* turtles, let's do just that using a *prototype* and turtle's `clone()` method:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLORS = ['black', 'red']

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def draw_squares(rows, columns, height=45, width=85, border=5):
    prototype = Turtle('square', visible=False)
    prototype.shapesize(height / CURSOR_SIZE, width / CURSOR_SIZE, border)
    prototype.pencolor('white')
    prototype.penup()

    x = -width / 2 * (columns // 2 * 2 + columns % 2 - 1)  # center on widow
    y = -height / 2 * (rows // 2 * 2 + rows % 2 -1)

    squares = []

    for column in range(columns):
        for row in range(rows):
            square = prototype.clone()
            square.fillcolor(COLORS[(column + row) % len(COLORS)])
            square.goto(column * width + x, row * height + y)
            square.showturtle()
            squares.append(square)

    return squares

screen = Screen()

squares = draw_squares(3, 5)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]